# How to set Yii2's ActiveForm checkbox in checked state?

Tags: checkbox, yii2, active-form

I'm looking for a simple solution for a "checked" state for the Yii2 ActiveForm checkbox control and I can't find a solution how to set it. I cant find any examples in the documentation.

I've tried to manipulate the rendering code

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->checkbox()->label('Hi'); ?>
```

But it seems I need to modify the ActiveForm itself. How to make checkbox checked by default?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've debbuged a while and found a solution, it lies in the guts of BaseHtml.php at line 1359 in activeCheckbox() function

```
$checked = "$value" === "{$options['value']}";
```

It checks for the default value of the model variable:

```
class SomeForm extends Model
{
    public $name = true;
```

And the same value (with the same type) must be assigned to the 'value' option in

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->checkbox(['value' => true])->label('Hi'); ?>
```

I would say it's overcomplicated as for such trivial feature.

Answer (score 2):

See, in my code `status` is either 0 or 1.

So, for checked checkbox., I declared `<?php $model->status = 1; ?>`

```
<?php $model->status = 1; ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'status')->checkbox()->label('Hi'); ?>
```

For example, if you are having 2 values for checkbox name i.e. PHP or Java. Then, declare it as `<?php $model->name = 'Java'; ?>` for getting Java as `checked`

```
//Your Code

<?php $model->name = 'Java'; ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->checkbox()->label('Hi'); ?>
```

Comment: Please tell me the reason of downvote. The one who did downvote, have you tried in your system?. Some people simply come to SO to downvote. If you think, this answer is not useful, please give reason/suggestion. **Don't Simply Downvote**

Comment: I Agree with you, this answer is the only answer that follows Yii way to set the checkbox checked when the form loads, `+1` for you and threat for the downvoter ** ̿ ̿'̿'\̵͇̿̿\з=(•_•)=ε/̵͇̿̿/'̿'̿ ̿**

Answer (score 1):

If I want to have a checked checkbox on create I do something like this in a view:

```
if ($model->isNewRecord) {
    $model->status = TRUE;
}
```

I know it's not an elegant solution, but it is working.